# Android redraw view on language change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, redraw

My target is do redraw view on language change. I have successfully detach and attach current fragment, but drawer items are not translated. I **DO NOT** want to use `Activity.recreate()` and I have already tried:

```
 View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.my_view);
 myView.invalidate();
```

with no success...

Comment: Can you try to call the requestLayout() method instead?

Comment: not working either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion to make your UI modification by a single function. and call it from onActivityCreated or onCreateView as per your code. So now whenever you will change the language, just call that function, it will take care of updating all the view automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Update the AndroidManifest file with the following configuration:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

In the activity level. This will trigger the:

```
onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

You can override this method in your code and refresh the view from there. For more info have a look [at this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: @TeodorKolev Have you gave it a try? Please let me clarify something. The "on language change" means that you have changed the language from the system, right? If so, that means that if you add the config into the AndroidManifest, the activity won't be recreated and remains running and the onConfigurationChanged() method is called. This is from the link above that's from the official Android documentation. Then before call the super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig), try to invalidate the view.